# Exclude an applink subdomain in the entitlements

Tags: ios, iphone

When dealing with universal links, how can I exclude a specific subdomain? What should I add in my entitlement file if I wanted to exclude `help.example.com` so that that url is opened in the browser?

My entitlement file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"     "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.developer.associated-domains</key>
    <array>
        <string>applinks:www.example.com</string>
        <string>applinks:*.example.com</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: You should do this in your apple-app-site-association by adding "NOT /path/to/exclude" to paths. Documentation url: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html

Comment: It looks like "NOT" is only for paths. I think it does not work for subdomains (I tried with a custom response with Charles and it did not work)

Comment: Did problem resolved?